# How did Vanessa know to come prepared?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, daredevil

At the end of their second romantic dinner (Daredevil, S1E5 "World on fire"), Wilson Fisk asks Vanessa

> about the gun in her purse.

Now, I understand that she was, understandably, a bit suspicious after what had happened in the previous rendez-vous, with Anatoly storming the place.

She replies candidly and it almost seems that she knows at least some detail about him. How is this possible, given his efforts to keep a low profile?
Have I misunderstood?

> And where did she get hold of a gun, given her job as an art gallery owner ? She surrenders it to him without any problem, like if it was a "disposable item"...

Comment: As you may or may not have gathered from recent news and controversy, in the United States (where Daredevil takes place), it is not difficult to obtain a gun via legal or illegal means.

Comment: I am aware of that ;-) But at that point of the story she didn't appear to have taken an illegal way of life. In any case it seems that her action were not surprising to US audience so I will proceed to accept @Mike Edenfield answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, I don't think "getting a gun" is anything overly suspicious. Real-world NY state law would allow her to get one simply by applying for a permit, though inside New York City she'd probably be breaking the law by carrying it in her purse. But that assumes that MCU's New York has the same gun laws as real-world New York, which may not be true.

Beyond that, though, she's a relatively wealthy and important single woman who lives or works in / around Hell's Kitchen. She's probably carried a handgun around for a very long time. Deciding to bring it to her dinner date is, as you say, most likely just a reaction to their previous one.

(Choosing to surrender it to Fisk simply showed that she no longer felt like she needed to have it, or at least, that she didn't think it would be of any use to her as long as Fisk was around. I'd wager she got it back at the end of the date.)

But, it *is* strongly implied that she knows more about Fisk than she lets on. She picked up very quickly, from a single encounter, that he's a dangerous person with dangerous acquaintances. While she may not have pegged him as Kingpin right away, she certainly knew that he was more than he seemed.

Over the course of the season Fisk reveals everything about his "business" to her and at no point does she act shocked or surprised. She falls very quickly into helping and supporting him in what he does, even as it gets *very* out of control. (In the source comics, she's a pretty ruthless character in her own right, which seems to be the direction she's heading in the MCU).

Comment: Yes I have gone further in the episodes and I have seen that she is not easily scared. Maybe I was just looking at the scene with european eyes, but it seemed like an unlikely gun owner and so I was surprised. Why she surrenders it is clear, but usually one would be very careful not to lose such a dangerous item which could be recorded and which one could be called to answer for....

Comment: yes; I think a US viewer wouldn't find it all that unusual for her to have "acquired" a gun; especially in a crime-ridden area like Hell's Kitchen they're probably cheap and available on the black market.